# Supplying a custom error handler in scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I've followed the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Supplying-a-custom-error-handler) and also added the custom error handler config in application.conf. But when I intentionally throw divide by 0: I get the following which show I'm still using `DefaultHttpErrorHandler`:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ArithmeticException: / by zero]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180)
```

Below are the code and addition details:

```
package services.cx

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc._

import javax.inject._
import scala.concurrent._

@Singleton
class CustomErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {
  lazy val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger")

  override def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
    Future.successful(
      Status(statusCode)("A client error occurred: " + message)
    )
  }

  override def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = {
    logger.error(
      "onServerError Exception occurred And logged In Error Handler and Exception is " + exception.getMessage
    )
    exception.printStackTrace()
    Future.successful(
      InternalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage)
    )
  }
}
```

In `application.conf`, I've put `play.http.errorHandler = "services.cx.CustomErrorHandler"`

Here's my ApplicationLoader.scala

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.filters.cors.CORSComponents
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilterComponents
...

class MyLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
      _.configure(context.environment)
    }
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem.create()
    new MyComponents(context, actorSystem).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(context: Context, system: ActorSystem)
    extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
    with CORSComponents
    with EhCacheComponents
    with GzipFilterComponents {
    ...
    override val httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(corsFilter, requestsCounterFilter, gzipFilter)
    ...
    lazy val customErrorHandler = new CustomErrorHandler()

    lazy val myRoutesV1 = new myapp_V1.Routes(customErrorHandler, myControllerV1)
    lazy val myRoutesV2 = new myapp_v2.Routes(customErrorHandler, myControllerV2)  
    lazy val router = new Routes(customErrorHandler, myRoutesV1, myRoutesV2)
}
```

In application.conf will have `play.application.loader = MyLoader`

I'm using

- play version 2.6
- scala 2.11
- Compile Time Dependency Injection [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection)

Comment: Any chance other parts of your code have a direct usage of the default handler? Does it work if not using compile time dependency?

Comment: could you provide more details? If you are using compile time DI, I guess you have your custom ApplicationLoader and you added some other properties in your application.conf file. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @GastónSchabas  As it is compile time DI, I've a custom ApplicationLoader in that I have multiple Routers I am using HttpErrorHandler in all of them. But there I changed them to use my CustomErrorHandler (like this `new CustomErrorHandler()`).

Comment: As you can see in the docs of compile time DI, the routes receive the error handler as parameter

Comment: With the provided code is not enough to understand or guess what is the issue you have. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or at least add enough parts of the project like the application loader and the routers

Comment: @GastónSchabas I have updated with ApplicationLoader. Hope it helps!